# Breadboard jumper cable to PCB

Tags: pcb, breadboard

I want to do some prototyping with a microcontroller on a breadboard.

The microcontroller won't fit in the breadboard holes because it is square and small, and has many pins I won't be using.

I would like to connect the pins of the microcontroller to the breadboard via the standard jumper cables (22 AWG) to a female socket. I've tried to find them, with no luck.

Perhaps someone here could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What package is it in?  You may be able to get a breakout board of some sort.

Comment: @alex.forencich Its a PIC18F97J60, a small square 100 pin IC

Comment: The easiest way to prototype with this is to use a breakout board like this one:http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Gertrude:_Microchip_TQFP-100_breakout_board_development

Comment: @RJR is that board compatible with the PIC18F family? It doesnt say so on there website, but they are in the TQFP-100 format

Comment: @bobsterman I'm not sure - I'd say have a look at the schematic to see if they're compatible. The other option is a renerig TQFP-100 breakout, but since you'd probably want the crystal and decoupling caps as close as possible to the chip, that might not be ideal.

Comment: @bobsterman - a quick glance at http://circuits.datasheetdir.com/19/PIC18F96J65-pinout.jpg and http://circuits.datasheetdir.com/19/PIC24FJ64GA010-pinout.jpg looks like it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend getting a breakout board for the chip.  You can either get a breakout board for the specific chip that contains some support components, or you can get a generic breakout board that provides a DIP form factor pinout for all of the chip pins.  For a 100-TQFP, this should not be terribly difficult to find.